# Why is jquery scrollto smooth scroll only working locally, but doesn't on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

> I was using the cdn versions initially, but thought it'd work if I used my own files (Doesn't Work).

```
<html>
<!-- Scripts --> 
<script src="/Users/anthony/CoderJonesFolio3/CoderJonesFolio3/WebFolio/assets/js/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="/Users/anthony/CoderJonesFolio3/CoderJonesFolio3/WebFolio/assets/js/jQueryscrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="/Users/anthony/CoderJonesFolio3/CoderJonesFolio3/WebFolio/assets/js/jQuerylocalScroll.js"></script>
<script src="/Users/anthony/CoderJonesFolio3/CoderJonesFolio3/WebFolio/assets/js/helper.js"></script>
```

> Updated src path to absolute (Works).

```
<html>
<!-- Scripts that work -->
<script src="./assets/js/JQuery.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/jQueryscrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/jQuerylocalScroll.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/helper.js"></script>
```

Comment: It will work, just make sure you have the correct files and that you are picking them up from the right place / folder

Comment: check the browser developer tools for any errors in loading your javascript content

Comment: Thanks, @Juan, I'll give that a shot

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX, I'll try that as well

Comment: After checking the console I see that all of my scripts are failing to load w/ 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. But why does this not occur locally?

Comment: make the paths relative to the document root "js/jQuery.js" etc